# create column to table programmatically in ms access

Tags: vb.net

I tried to programmatically create an Access 2007 table with code and create columns inside the table. But there was a problem with me, I cannot add properties to the columns.

Required :

1- Text column : I need to add the non-repetition property. Name of the property indexed =Yes (No Duplicates)
2- Single numeric column : I want to make the default value the property  default value = 0
3-  Date column : I want to make column properties property  format = Short Date or medium time

The following code adds columns without the required properties

```
 Using conA As New OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\test.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123456")
            conA.Open()
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
                cmd.Connection = conA
                cmd.CommandText = ("CREATE TABLE sample1 ([id] COUNTER IDENTITY(1,1),[intnumb] Single ,[SessionId] VARCHAR (40), [SessionDate] DATETIME,[SessionName] LONGTEXT, CONSTRAINT PKSessions PRIMARY KEY (id))")
                Try
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Console.WriteLine("Table column created.")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End Using
            conA.Close()
        End Using
```

Comment: What is the Error message ?

Comment: no error The code is incomplete. No properties were added for each column

Comment: The syntax for the `CREATE TABLE` statement in Access is detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql). If that doesn't tell you how to do what you want to do then it can't be done, so you'll have to look elsewhere for how to do it. It may be that it cannot be done via SQL and requires ADO/DAO. Certain Access features do.

Comment: Can the part be modified. Of the properties of date .about this 3- Date column : I want to make column properties property format = Short Date or medium time

Comment: Can the Ace provider by used by a Jet database? Just saw the Jet reference in the connection string. I am not sure when Access versions switched to Ace but 2007 seems kind of old.